# Really need help for this script part for the control of django formset with a button

Tags: jquery, django

To all the pros out there, i really need help with this. 2 days ago my code work. Now its haywire. This line **'$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', (parseInt (totalForms))-1);'** is the issue. 2 days ago, without this line, everything works. The button to control the number of formset and its saved the number of data accordingly. But now without the same line, it cannot even control the counting properly. And to make it worst, it delete the last row of data whenever i saved.

Here's what happen in detail: Upon loading the page, user can clone up to additional 3 formsets to key in data. So with the original one. Theres 4 rows in total. If user clicks save, all 4 rows get saved properly. If user never click save but instead click the '-' button on one of the row to remove the one of the row. It becomes 2 additional formsets and the original remaining. Total 3 rows of data. But if at this time user clicks save, it somehow delete one more additional formsets due to the line **$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', (parseInt (totalForms))-1);**

**But this morning, without using this line everything works perfectly**

```
    let maxrow = $('#id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS').attr('value');
    let totalForms = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();


    // Show the total # of forms on run (default is 1)
    console.log(totalForms);


    $('#deleteConfirmation').modal('hide');

    

    $('#addrow').click(function () {
        
        let totalForms = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        console.log(totalForms)

        $('#empty-form #removerow').css('display','block');
        
        
        let wholerowclone = $('#empty-form').clone();
        
        $('#morerows').append(wholerowclone.html().replace(/__prefix__/g, totalForms));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', (parseInt (totalForms))+1);
  
       

        
        if(totalForms==maxrow) {
            
            $('#addrow').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#addrow').attr("class","btn btn-rounded btn-danger");
            $('#addrow i').attr("class","");
            $('#addrow').html("Reached max limit");
        }

    
        
    })


   
    

    $(document).on('click', '#removerow', function () {
        let totalForms = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        console.log(totalForms + " total forms");

        let actualformcount = totalForms-2;
        
 
        console.log(actualformcount + "actual form count");
        console.log(maxrow + "max");
        
        //$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', (parseInt (totalForms))-1);
     
     
        $(this).closest('#morerows .row').remove();
        if(actualformcount<maxrow){
            
            $('#addrow').attr("disabled", false)
            $('#addrow').attr("class","btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded")
            $('#addrow i').attr("class","dripicons-plus")
            $('#addrow').html("+") 
        }  
          
    });
```

HTML:

```
                          {{di_form.management_form}}

                            <div id = "rowAddition">
                            {% for form in di_form %}
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{di_form.moduletype.id_for_label}}">Module Type<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                {{form.moduletype}}               
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{di_form.firstportid.id_for_label}}">First Port ID<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            {{form.firstportid}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{di_form.lastportid.id_for_label}}">Last Port ID <span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            {{form.lastportid}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {%endfor%}

                            <div id="empty-form" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{dd_form.moduletype.id_for_label}}">Module Type<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                {{di_form.empty_form.moduletype}}               
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{di_form.firstportid.id_for_label}}">First Port ID<span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            {{di_form.empty_form.firstportid}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{di_form.lastportid.id_for_label}}">Last Port ID <span
                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            {{di_form.empty_form.lastportid}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="text-sm-center">
                                                <br />
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded"
                                                    id="removerow" style="display: none;"><i class="dripicons-minus"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 
                                <hr><br><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                            <!--more rows-->
                            <div id='morerows'>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Is this a DJANGO issue AT ALL? If not, please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with RENDERED html and JavaScript and relevant CSS only. Also change the title to something relevant. Also please post any errors from the console

Comment: Where is `<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS"` defined and are you cloning that too? IDs must be unique

Comment: It is not? This script is to control the django formset i have. So i assume i have to tag django along. And isnt the total forms something that comes with django formset?@mplungjan

Comment: Again: Please click [edit], then the buttons that looks like `[<>]` and post a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML!!! Please  - we cannot guess the problem if we cannot run your jQuery. And the HTML needs to include the fields you are using in the jQuery such as id_form-TOTAL_FORMS

Comment: The codes wont work. id_form is auto generated by django when run together in the web

Comment: so you view-source and post that HTML

Comment: The entire code is too long

Comment: Then you only post enough for a [mcve]